# Using pyttsx3 with tkinter causes program to stop and close, any ideas?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, macos-mojave, pyttsx

I installed the `pyttsx3` libary to convert text to speech. And it works really great, until I want to use it in combination with `tkinter`. What happens that the program just closes, without any errors or what so ever. Weird enough it goes through the codes after `engine.runAndWait()`. I checked that by putting a print command after every line which shows up in the terminal, but I it 'ignores' the widgets that are supposed to be built up in the window. Any ideas? I'm using MacOs Mojave 10.14.6. with Python 3.8.5.

Here is the partial code with the problem, you can obviously ignore the print commands in between. I just left it so it's visible that it goes through the code, but only executing the print commands and ignoring the rest. Again, it works fine without `tkinter`, and the program also works fine when I don't use the `pyttsx3` library. Here's the whole code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/rezzJ7ex and the JSON file that goes with it: https://www.codepile.net/pile/ePlYvbZM

```
 else:
        random.shuffle(WORDS)
        for widget in window.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        WORD = WORDS[0]
        tk.Label (window, image=photo1, bg="black") .grid(row=0, column=0)
        word = tk.Label (window, text = WORD, bg="black", fg="white", font="none 20 bold")
        word.grid(row=1, column=0)
        window.update()
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        nl_voice_id = "com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.ellen"
        engine.setProperty('rate', 100)
        engine.setProperty('voice', nl_voice_id)
        engine.say(WORD)
        engine.runAndWait()
        #del engine <this did not work
        print("after runAndWait")
        window.after(3000)
        print("after after")
        word['text'] = ''
        print("after text")
        window.update()
        print("after update")
        ANSWER = tk.Entry(window, width=20, bg="white")
        print("after entry")
        ANSWER.grid(row=2, column=0)
        print("after ANSWER")
        tk.Button(window, text="Check", width=6, command=lambda: check(ANSWER,WORD)) .grid(row=3, column=0)
        print("after button")
        WORDS.remove(WORD)
        print("after remove")
```

Comment: When you run the code, no window is shown?

Comment: @CoolCloud, thanks. No the window is there and it builds Label and word.grid, but everything else (other than the print commands) are not executed after engine.runAndWait() and the window closes.